# Is there a term that encompasses all the different classifiers which do not consider the order of features?

Tags: classification, references, terminology

Some time ago I read a term (or compact expression) used to encompass all the different classification algorithms that do not consider the ordering or spatial relation of features (eg SVMs, Multilayer Perceptrons, Logistic Regression, Naive Bayes ...). Unfortunately, I can not remember the expression. Can you help with this? I would also appreciate it if you could provide a reference where this nomenclature is used.

An example of a classifier not in this category would be the Convolutional Neural Network. In this case, reordering features (e.g., changing the spatial position of pixels in an image) would affect the classification accuracy.

Comment: I would call them _"agnostic toward X"_ where "X" is the specific ordering or spatial correlation you mentioned, but I have no source for this usage of the term.

Comment: Although quite similar, that is not the precise expression I was looking for.